# i want to find a word's first letter's strpos in a paragraph

Tags: php

To find a word's first letter with `strpos()` in a paragraph. i tried by fetching all first letters of the word in paragraph..

```
$paragraph = "A pangram or holoalphabetic win sentence is a sentence that contains every knight letter of the alphabet at least once.  
              The most famous pangram is probably the thirty-five-letter-long The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog,  
              which has been used to test typing equipment since at least the late Pangrams are an important tool for 
              testing typing equipment and compactly showing off every letter of price related etc";

$array = range('a','z');

// to find the first letter of each word in the paragraph 

$words = explode(" ", $paragraph);
$letters = "";
foreach ($words as $value) {
    $letters .= substr($value, 0, 1);
}

$countLetters = strtolower($letters);
```

======================================================================

if i give 'p' as a selected alphabet then i want to find the string position of first and last word of it ..

first word in the paragraph with p  =  "pangram" --> find strpos of p ...

last word in paragraph with p  = "price" --> find strpos of p ...

ex..

```
output = {
            "p":{
                    "firstWordofFirstLetterPosition":2,
                    "firstWordofLastLetterPosition":"strpos of p in price"
                }
```

Comment: balaji  check my answer now.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/NsnZc

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted? With multibyte string support:

```
<?php

function firstWordsInParagraph(string $input, string $letter) {
    $lowercaseLetter = mb_strtolower($letter);

    // return only words having given letter
    $words = array_filter(explode(' ', $input), function ($word) use ($lowercaseLetter) {
        return mb_strpos(mb_strtolower($word), $lowercaseLetter) !== false;
    });

    // no matches found!
    if (empty($words)) {
        return [
            'firstWordofFirstLetterPosition' => null,
            'firstWordofLastLetterPosition' => null,
        ];
    }

    return [
        'firstWordofFirstLetterPosition' => mb_strpos(current($words), $lowercaseLetter),
        'firstWordofLastLetterPosition' => mb_strpos(end($words), $lowercaseLetter),
    ];
}

$input = 'kolorowa żółć w żniw pożodze';
$letter = 'ż';

print_r(firstWordsInParagraph($input, $letter));
```

eg: https://3v4l.org/7Go7i

returns:

```
Array (
   [firstWordofFirstLetterPosition] => 0
   [firstWordofLastLetterPosition] => 2
)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you try with a regular expression you can archive this in a more simple and readable way

```
<?php

$paragraph = "A pangram or holoalphabetic win sentence is a sentence that contains every knight letter of the alphabet at least once.  
              The most famous pangram is probably the thirty-five-letter-long The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog,  
              which has been used to test typing equipment since at least the late Pangrams are an important tool for 
              testing typing equipment and compactly showing off every letter of price related etc";

$findMe = 'p';

function getPositionAndWordsFromParagraph($paragraph,$findMe){
    $output_array = [];
    preg_match_all('/\b['.$findMe.']/', $paragraph, $output_array, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    $first = array_shift($output_array[0]);
    $last = array_pop($output_array[0]);
    return [
        $findMe => [
            'firstWordofFirstLetterPosition' => $first[1],
            'firstWordofLastLetterPosition' => $last[1]
        ]
    ];
}

print_r(getPositionAndWordsFromParagraph($paragraph,$findMe));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
<?php
$paragraph = "A pangram or holoalphabetic win sentence is a sentence that contains every knight letter of the alphabet at least once.  
              The most famous pangram is probably the thirty-five-letter-long The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog,  
              which has been used to test typing equipment since at least the late Pangrams are an important tool for 
              testing typing equipment and compactly showing off every letter of price related etc";

function findFirstLastPositionOfWordsStartingWith($findMe, $string){
    $matches = [];
    preg_match_all('/\b('.$findMe.'.*)\b/i',$string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    $matches = $matches[1];
    return [
        "firstWordofFirstLetterPosition" => reset($matches)[1],
        "firstWordofLastLetterPosition" => end($matches)[1],
    ];
}

var_dump(findFirstLastPositionOfWordsStartingWith('p', $paragraph));
var_dump(findFirstLastPositionOfWordsStartingWith('a', $paragraph));
```

The above will output the following:

```
array(2) {
  ["firstWordofFirstLetterPosition"]=>
  int(2)
  ["firstWordofLastLetterPosition"]=>
  int(450)
}
array(2) {
  ["firstWordofFirstLetterPosition"]=>
  int(0)
  ["firstWordofLastLetterPosition"]=>
  int(408)
}
```